# Javafx- How to add text in editable combobox text editor to database if entry not found

Tags: java, javafx

I have a combobox that gets its items from a certain column in a database. The combobox is editable so that the user can write items that is not in the database. The question: how can I check if the new text entered in the combobox is new and then add it to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a ComboBox with String-items, you could write something like this:

```
if (!comboBox.getItems().contains(userEnteredText)) {
    insertIntoDatabase(userEnteredText);
    comboBox.getItems().add(userEnteredText);
}
comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(userEnteredText);
```

Comment: Tobi, thank you so much for this piece of code. It works fine and is easy to use.